# R Extract Table Function from Tabulizer to Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tabulizer

I'm trying to extract tables from PDFs using the Tabulizer library. I extracted the 1st page with no issue and then converted it to a data frame. After that, I was just cutting the edges of all data frames to get the info required.

When trying to extract the 2nd, and trying to convert it to a data frame, it tells "arguments imply differing number of rows". The solution for this is to use "reshape2" package, but it was not helpful for me.

Is there any way to fill the missing spaces with NAs, so I can be able to convert it to a data frame?

This is how it looks on R Studio.

[5 Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zi88.png)

I did not have any problem converting the 1st one to a data frame, this is the code:

```
tables <- extract_tables(proform, pages = 1) %>% as.data.frame()
```

This is the PDF I'm trying to convert:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aOdXkj6W_Y7sQaoLq8HtYxGBMA7IAtuW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Not enough information to debug. Read [ask] and [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using "extract_areas" function from the Tabulizer package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).